# Python equivalent to Java's JNLP Web Start?

Tags: python, jnlp

Is there any way to achieve the same functionality in Python, i.e., launching a script from a browser and automatically updating it from a central server location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run your app on Jython and use Java Web Start?

From a comment below, http://blog.pyproject.ninja/posts/2016-03-31-web-start-on-jython.html, provides a complete example.

Note that Jython is not Python- some stuff does not work, and notably Jython is only Python-2.7 compatible.

Comment: This seems cynical at first but is actually a pretty good suggestion.

Comment: @alex Can u give a pseudo code example for the same

Comment: For getting started with Jython and Web Start, check out my blog post http://blog.pyproject.ninja/posts/2016-03-31-web-start-on-jython.html

Answer (score 2):

Well this is still not a full match of the features of JNLP but maybe [esky](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky) is closer to what you want. It's not browser based but once your app is installed on the client it can update itself. It might also lack something in the cross-platform department so depending on your environment YMMV.

Another alternative might be the Dabo framework at dabodev.com. It's been a few years since i looked at that but it still looks like it's alive :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve some functionality with [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) although it uses classless python, so its functionality is rather limited.

Well check out [this python wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming) as it lays out various options.

Comment: I find a lot of web stuff on those pages, but still the JNLP-like functionality seems to missing. Just having the ability to download up-to-date scripts from a central server (or not if the local scripts are updated just fine) is a godsend in a scenario with plenty of client computers running the same few scripts etc. I would have thought the Python community would have come up with a 'port' long time ago...